# Is there a noun for a man who wrote a best-seller book?

Tags: vocabulary

Is there a noun for a man who wrote a best-seller book? Or shall we describe by "this man who wrote a best-seller book"?

Comment: How about "millionaire"

Answer (score 62, accepted):

There is no single word for this concept, but you can call a man (or a woman!) a *best-selling author.*

Comment: Or a "best-selling novelist" if it's that sort of book.